# How do I build a new object that contains a List<string> as attribute?

Tags: c#

So, in my main `form` class I have the following list, which is populated by user input:

```
List<string> ProduseAlese = new List<string>();
```

And after it's populated, it's going into this constructor:

```
Comenzi comanda = new Comenzi(nrCom, dataCom, dataLiv, factura, ProduseAlese);
```

And my class looks like this:

```
public class Comenzi
{
    public int NrComanda { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataComanda { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataLivrare { get; set; }
    public List<string> Articole { get; set; }
    public Facturi Factura { get; set; }

    public Comenzi(int nrcomanda, DateTime datacomanda, DateTime datalivrare, Facturi _factura, List<string> _articole)
    {
        NrComanda = nrcomanda;
        DataComanda = datacomanda;
        DataLivrare = datalivrare;
        Factura = _factura;
    }
}
```

What do I have to write in the constructor?
The point is to copy the items from the initial list into the newly created object.

Comment: You probably just want `Articole = _articole;`. Unless you want to create a separate copy of the list, then you can use something like `Articole = new List<string>(_articole);` or `Articole = _articole.ToList();`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I thought that it's more complicated for lists.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public List<string> Articole { get; set; } = new List<string>();
public Facturi Factura { get; set; }

public Comenzi(int nrcomanda, DateTime datacomanda, DateTime datalivrare, Facturi _factura, List<string> _articole)
{
    NrComanda = nrcomanda;
    DataComanda = datacomanda;
    DataLivrare = datalivrare;
    Factura = _factura;
    _articole = _articole?? new List<string>();
    Articole.AddRange(_articole.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This will throw a null reference exception.  You don’t new Articole before calling AddRange.

Comment: No it won't. See the first line.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to copy the list objects into a new list, you can use the `ToList()` method from the `System.Linq` namespace.

```
Articole = _articole.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't "have to" use the class constructor to feed all your object data, unless there is a requirement needing you to do so.

Since your properties are public you could asign a value to them after creating the object

```
Comenzi comanda = new Comenzi(nrCom, dataCom, dataLiv, factura);
comanda.Articole = ProduseAlese;
```

Keep in mind that as you're developing your application your class definition might grow and is not a good practice to fill ALL the properties in the constructor. You have to keep only the ones that are mandatory for your objects of that class.

Comment: If you still want a new List instead of a reference to the original, you can use comanda.Articole = ProduseAlese.ToList();